# ¿se puede escribir en un archivo dentro del jar?

Tags: java, jar

tengo un archivo de text dentro del jar, el cual leo con este metodo:

```
public String leerArchivo(String ruta) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String stringFromBytes = null;
    try {
        inputStream = tiendaSuvenirs.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ruta);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] bytesOfStream = inputStream.readAllBytes(); //  los bytes del archivo de exportaciones.            
        stringFromBytes = new String(bytesOfStream); // convertir los bytes a un string.            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeResources(inputStream);
    }        
    return stringFromBytes;
}
```

y para llamar al metodo lo hago asi:`modoRemotoOLocal = leerArchivo("resources/modoRemotoOLocal.txt");`
Pero ahora necesito escribir en ese archivo y no se si es posible. Para ello lo he intentado con este metodo:

```
public void escribirArchivo(String ruta, String texto) {

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(tiendaSuvenirs.class.getResource(ruta).getPath()));
            writer.write(texto);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tiendaSuvenirs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Pero no lo he conseguido. ¿Es posible escribir a un archivo dentro del jar?

Comment: si se puede, no, no quieres :)

Comment: Hola @raposo. Pareciera que estas usando el jar como si fuera una especie de repositorio en el que metes cosas, haces cambios y sacas cosas. En principio leer algo de un jar no esta mal, pero estar escribiendo no es muy practico. El jar es en realidad un ZIP por lo que para escribir en el lo normal seria descomprimirlo, cambiar el contenido y volver a comprimir. No es eficiente. Si quieres leer y modificar datos de archivos lo natural es que no lo hagas sobre archivos que estén en  un jar.

Comment: En tu pregunta pon más detalles, cada cuanto vas a escribir, que vas a escribir, si el jar solo tiene el archivo o si tiene otra cosa, etc. De entrada si a mi me pidieran escribir lo primero que propondría sería abandonar el uso del archivo del jar y en su lugar utilizar un archivo que se ubique en el mismo lugar donde esta el programa. Saludos.

Comment: Claro Alvaro, asi es como lo venia haciendo hasta ahora y funcionaba bien. Pero quise hacerlo con un archivo jar para que al generar el dist (con clean and build) me incluyese ese archivo en el paquete. Esto es para despreocuparme de andar copiando el archivo de texto en la raiz del proyecto cada vez que hago un clean and built. El archivo es para seleccionar el tipo de conexion a la base de datos (si es en el equipo local o en el remoto), de tal forma que seria en el archivo de texto donde guardo una cadena de texto (local o remoto) en cada caso. Se escribiria cada vez que se cambie el modo.